# (Java) use one code for multiple responses?

Tags: java

If in a code, I have two options - choosing 1 or 2 -- in '2' you go straight to another code, but with '1' you must do a few things before and then do to that code, is this possible with one code? This is an example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
reader = scanner.nextInt();
if (reader == 1) {
    System.out.println("Not yet, pick another one");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();           
}
} else if (reader == 2) {
    System.out.println("Okay, you have picked 2!");
}
```

Is it possible to go directly from the first to the second? Provided the first one picks '2' in the second try, do I have to retype the code in that area or can I move it directly to the `else if(reader == 2){....}` code after this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just modify you're conditions a bit:

```
int someVar = ...;

if(someVar == 1){
    ...
    //do stuff before other code
}

...
//do stuff you do for 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use else-if in this scenario, since the else-if part will never be evaluated if the first condition is true. You need two separate conditions :

```
int reader = scanner.nextInt();
if (reader == 1){
    System.out.println("Not yet, pick another one");
    reader = scanner.nextInt();           
}
if (reader == 2) {
    System.out.println("Okay, you have picked 2!");
}
```

Note that you also have to read both integers into the same variable.